# JMH ArrayList LinkedList Performance test

Tags: java, jmh

The following performance test is wrong

Adding operation to list directly, the test result is incorrect

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
@State(Scope.Thread)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 1, time = 1)
@Measurement(iterations = 1, time = 1)
@Fork(1)
public class ListBenchmark1 {
    public List<String> array  = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<String> linked = new LinkedList<>();

    @Benchmark
    public void testArray(Blackhole bh) {
        array.add("1");
        bh.consume(array);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void testLinked(Blackhole bh) {
        linked.add("1");
        bh.consume(linked);
    }
}
```

```
Benchmark                   Mode  Cnt         Score   Error  Units
ListBenchmark1.testArray   thrpt       49775951.966          ops/s
ListBenchmark1.testLinked  thrpt        2711816.352          ops/s
```

ArrayList > LinkedList

This is a correct performance test

An intermediate class is used to store attributes, and the list in the class is added, and the test result is correct

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 1, time = 1)
@Measurement(iterations = 1, time = 1)
@Fork(1)
public class ListBenchmark {

    @State(Scope.Thread)
    public static class ArrayClass {
        public List<String> list;

        @Setup(Level.Invocation)
        public void setup() {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    @State(Scope.Thread)
    public static class LinkedClass {
        public List<String> list;

        @Setup(Level.Invocation)
        public void setup() {
            list = new LinkedList<>();
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public List<String> testArray(ArrayClass array) {
        array.list.add("1");
        return array.list;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public List<String> testLinked(LinkedClass linked) {
        linked.list.add("1");
        return linked.list;
    }
}
```

```
Benchmark                   Mode  Cnt         Score   Error  Units
ListBenchmark.testArray    thrpt       23828227.679          ops/s
ListBenchmark.testLinked   thrpt       28603947.913          ops/s
```

ArrayList < LinkedList

Why are the results of these two different test methods incorrect

They are all add operations. Why is there such a contrast?

Comment: "Why are the results of these two different test methods incorrect" Did you mean to ask why is _the first one_ incorrect? Because you just said the second one is correct.

Comment: How do you determine that the first test is incorrect and the second one is correct?

Comment: @Sweeper first wrong,It was wrong and corrected, and the first test was wrong

Comment: Btw: a benchmark with one (1) warmup run and iteration is useless and will not be accurate

Comment: @Amongalen Because arraylist is an array implementation and linkedlist is a linked list implementation, the add operation LinkedList is definitely faster than arraylist

Comment: @Tony wang I would expect the ArrayList to be much faster than the LInkedList to add new elements to a list overall. But to be precise, each would have better/worse performance depending on usage. ArrayList is really not good if you tend to remove elements often. It would be good for iterating, must faster for random access and most often faster for adding element (as the array is not resized for each addition).

Comment: I would not benchmarch a single addition to the list but at least like 10 in a single method call and I would also try with list of various size and with different number of elements added. Also to get accurate measurement, in java, you need to let the time for the JIT to do its works. Do more like measurements of 10 seconds and like 20 warmup and 20 measurements to get more accurate result. And finally when you say the results are correct/incorrect, you must provide the actual results you got from JMH here, just not juge for yourself.

Comment: @NicolasBousquet I know what you said, but what I want to know is the question I raised.

Comment: You know but you don't provide the JMH results so we can't figure out "incorrect" and you keep a test that make no sense (single iteration, not time for JIT...) and ask why the results make no sense. What the point ? You also say that the linked list is definitely faster while we would expect the opposite. All of this is funny.

Comment: @NicolasBousquet update content,Why is the result different? Do not understand ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now with number given by JMH it is much better.

**First run**

First run you grow the list to a huge size (as you don't re-create them each time) so you mostly measure the performance of adding one more element to an already huge list. Interrestingly this test isn't fair as the faster list (ArrayList there as expected) grow to bigger size and has to manager this bigger size.

This is what we would expect anyway.

**Second run**

On the second run, you do a re-init of the list between each run AND you do very simple operation in the run. This force JMH to perform measurement between each call instead of doing many calls and get an overall measurement.

This means you results are going to be far less precize and that you don't measure the same thing at all. You measure growing a list from size 0 to 1.

On top if you look at the source code of ArrayList, the allocation of the array is done ONLY when you add the first element. When the list is created, there no allocation.

So ArrayList perform poorly on the second test because your have this big allocation of an array of 10 elements (https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java).

Would you add an element to each list in the init and then benchmark the addition of one more element, ArrayList would again become much faster than LinkedList.

**Still**

To get accurate result, make more iterations and a significant warm-up time. For me operation per second shall be at least one order of magnitude faster.

Also be sure that you don't grow your list to be too big as this would otherwise get you an OutOfMemory error.

Comment: Isn't first run linked list add op faster? Why is the throughput so low?

Comment: Not it isn't. Each time you add an element to a linked list, it create a Node and increase the size and link the new node to the existing list. On the ArrayList, it just put the object at the propoer index of the array and increment the size by one. There no memory allocation at all just an assignment and an increment of an int. It is only when the array need to be resized that the ArrayList is slower, and this is done only from time to time. When the array is too small, it doesn't grow by an increased size of 1 cell, but like 25% more.

Comment: Also if you want accurate throughput use longer run, longer warm up and more iterations. Like 20x10s for warm up and as much for measurement. Remember that Java is compiling the most commonly used code but only after it has been run a few time and that you don't want to measure the ocmpilation time neither.

Comment: [the results are on par](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63080920/1059372) once the code is hot enough

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to find out *if* there is a contrast when you add elements to these two lists, you might want to write a correct test first. For example:

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 5)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 5)
@Fork(1)
public class LinkedVsArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
            .include(LinkedVsArrayList.class.getSimpleName())
            .build();

        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

    @Param({"1", "10", "100", "1000", "10000"})
    public int howMany;

    @Benchmark
    public List<String> testArray() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < howMany; ++i) {
            list.add("" + i);
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public List<String> testLinked() {
        List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < howMany; ++i) {
            list.add("" + i);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

This will add `1`, `10`, `100`... elements to some `List`. I'll just show you the results for `100` and `1000`:

```
LinkedVsArrayList.testArray         100  thrpt    5  840.171 ± 111.088  ops/ms
LinkedVsArrayList.testLinked        100  thrpt    5  847.743 ± 111.039  ops/ms

LinkedVsArrayList.testArray        1000  thrpt    5   72.675 ±   5.367  ops/ms
LinkedVsArrayList.testLinked       1000  thrpt    5   69.218 ±   6.093  ops/ms
```

The results are very close to each other, which shows that even if `ArrayList` has an `array` behind the scenes (as opposed to `LinkedList`), this makes no difference.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly there is a lot here, let's take it slow. 1) Those examples are brilliant, but somehow (characteristic to Alexey at times) cryptic to understand. What I think he is trying to say is that a very smart compiler could transform : `1 + 42 + 2 + 42 + 3 + 42 + 4 + 42 .... 100 + 42` to `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + .... + 100 + 42 * 100`, which _can merge the operations between two otherwise distinct work_ (or any other transformation like that); which makes complete sense. 2) When you say: _add operations are getting faster as the number of elements grow_, should make sense (continued)

Comment: because the more elements you add into an `ArrayList` the bigger the inner array gets. Let's say the policy when the inner array is full is to double its size. So you add 8 elements (let's say it is full at the 8-th), you get 8 more elements where no resize is going to happen. When you add 16, 16 without a resize, and so on. So the more elements you add, the "further" is the resize. 3) There is a `@Param(1)` in example - it is up to the OP to run and see what the numbers are, I guess. (continued)

Comment: you have my attention now - this is getting interesting btw. Can you share the code for your tests? I think I understand how you tested it - but want to make sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226619/discussion-between-eugene-and-anthony-accioly).

Comment: The test done there for me is dominated by external operation not linked to list performance. The for loop and the concatenation of string. As such you can't really see how much faster/slowe a given implementation is. You are benchmarking the concatenations of strings instead. Also please notice that you howMany value are small... you should try with million of elements

Comment: @NicolasBousquet the fact that you say "millions of elements" shows that you do not really understand how JMH works. And the concatenation is equally present in _both_ benchmarks, skewing the results equally.

Comment: See the chat Eugene, my optimized code show without concatenation and int convertion and unrolled loop we got 5-6 time faster, And we see that with 10 million element ArrayList is twice as fast as LinkedList, With 100 million elements ArrayList is 20 time faster. The bigger the number of element, the more important the poor memory usage of the LinkedList show in the performance while on a small dataset, everything fit in cache. I used JMH for years and make actual production code much faster thank to it... And efficiant memory use is as important as to not do too complex computations.

Comment: The problem of the concatenation is that it take about 80-90% of the total time (we go like 5-6 time faster without it) meaning that whatever happen in the rest will not change the result much. Adding a constant to you measurement is anything but neutral. You just added a hidden feature in your test, You go as far as saying that other don't get how JMH works, thats quite agressive by the way.

Comment: @NicolasBousquet your bringing a lot points here, like 1) the chat: that is only about the fact that I miss-understood a bit the question and should have tested only a single element additon 2) "your optimized code": that I have no idea what it is or why does it matter 3) I will try those millions to see if you are right or not, and wil get back.

Comment: ""your optimized code": that I have no idea what it is or why does it matter" => It is in the chat. I also provided the benchmark results of my runs there.

Comment: @NicolasBousquet so what if String concatenations adds time to both results, at the same time. The times should _not_ be judged individually, anyway.

Comment: @NicolasBousquet I see. SO does not send a notification when a chat is updated, you should have started with that. I will respond in a bit

Comment: Let say you want to know what is faster to go to work by car or by foot, you can make the measurement from the moment you leave your home until your arrive to work. Let say you find 30 mins by walk and 10 min by car. So you conclude the car is 3 time as fast. Now imagine you include on top the time to wake up, shower and eat breakfast that take 1hour. Now the result are similar: 1h10 vs 1h30. But did you really want to measure that ? Was is your goal to mesure performance of int to string + concatenation or the perf of adding an element ? in JMH its criteral to remove all overhead.